# How to programmaticaly retrieve marked entry from docx

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

How can I retrieve marked entry (marked via pressing Alt+Shift+X. Word displays the Mark Index Entry dialog box) from docx document? I need to indentify it in and replace with specific content.
I create marked entries manulaly in ms word, but I need to retrieve it somehow.

What I've tried:

```
var wordApp = new Application();
wordApp.Visible = true;
var docxDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath);                           
var indexes= docxDocument.Indexes; // empty collection
```

Comment: If you're interested in plain text, what about just place it into clipboard (manually)?
Then in your app process clipboard (compare, replace,..) and than just via clipboard insert it back into MS Word.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean marked via pressing Alt+Shift+X in  ms word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that better solution will be using bookmarks.
Example of changing bookmark content:

```
var wordApp = new Application();
wordApp.Visible = true;
var docxDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath);

var bookmark = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks["MyBookmark"];                     
Range range = bookmark.Range;
range.Text = "My new text\n";
object rng = range;
var newBookmark = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add("NewBookmark", ref rng);
```